# Multiple conditions in XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to use XSLT to transform my XML document into a Bootstrap table. I have done it before using PHP and it was quite simple and I'm trying to adapt it in XSLT.

With PHP I did something like this :

```
while($line = $request->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
   echo '<tr ';
   switch($line["category"])
   {
     case "Movie" : echo "class='info'";break;
     case "Tv show" : echo "class='danger'";break;
     case "Music" : echo "class='success'";break;
   }
   echo ' >';
   ...
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

I tried to do a similar code in XSLT (not using concatenation because we can't) :

```
<xsl:for-each select="demands/demand">
    <xsl:choose> 
        <xsl:when test="category  = 'Movie'"> 
            <tr class="info">
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="category = 'Tv show'"> 
            <tr class="danger">
        </xsl:when> 
        <xsl:when test="categorie = 'Music'"> 
            <tr class="success">
        </xsl:when> 
    </xsl:choose>
    ...
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

That doesn't work ("Opening and ending tag mismatch: tr line") because there is only one closing tr tag. Is there any solution to that ? How can I do it the simpliest way ?

Thank's for your help.

Comment: You need to recognize that XSLT writes nodes to a tree, it does not write tags to a text file. You can't write half a node!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on Martin Honnen's solution, with slightly more code reuse, is

```
<xsl:template match="demands/demand">
  <tr>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@category"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@category[. = 'Movie']"
>info</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@category[. = 'Tv show']"
>danger</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@category[. = 'Music']"
>success</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

The right approach is to use

```
<xsl:template match="demands/demand[category = 'Movie']">
  <tr class="info">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="demands/demand[category = 'Tv show']">
  <tr class="danger">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="demands/demand[category = 'Music']">
  <tr class="success">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

and then your `...` is put into a generated by templates for the content of the `demand` elements.